# New Angular project missing the app folder

Tags: angularjs, git, atlassian-sourcetree

I noticed that a newly-setup Angular project was not registering the changes inside its `src/app` folder, so I looked at the project's `.gitignore` file, but there is nothing that is causing the whole `app` directory to be ignored...

Searching for the term 'app' returns the following, but they cannot be responsible, right?

```
AppPackages/
App/[pP]layers/
```

Regardless, I commented them out, but no change.

When I try to add the `app` folder in `GitBash`, I get the following:

```
$ git add app/
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
myAngularApp/src/app
```

I am confused what is causing this directory to be ignored. Can someone please help me understand what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply try to check which rule of which `.gitignore` is the cause for this error, using [`git check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore):

```
cd /path/to/repository
git check-ignore -v -- app/aFile_inside_app
```

That will give you a better idea of what is going on.

The [OP CatarinaRuna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14932840/catarinaruna) confirms:

> The command revealed that `[Aa]pp/` in my `.gitignore` was the cause, but it wouldn't show up in my search, because I only looked for `app` : )

Comment: Thank you! The command revealed that `[Aa]pp/` in my gitignore was the cause, but it wouldn't show up in my search, because I only looked for `app`  : )

Comment: @CatarinaRuna Good catch.